# Unsupported operand type error in python

Tags: python

```
def get_word_count(wordlist, final):
    regex = []
    count = [[] for x in xrange(len(wordlist))]
    frequency = []
    regex = makeregex(wordlist)
    for i in range(len(final)-1):
        size = os.stat(final[i]).st_size
        fil = open(final[i])
        if(fil):
            print final[i] + " read!"
            data = mmap.mmap(fil.fileno(), size, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
            for j in range (len(wordlist)):
                count[j].append(re.findall(regex[j], data))
        fil.close()
    for k in range(len(wordlist)):
        frequency.append(sum(count[k]))
    print frequency
```

`count` is a list of lists and every list has some numbers stored into it. I wish to store the sum of every list as an element to a new list `frequency`

When I run the code I get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Animesh\Desktop\_zipf.py", line 52, in <module>
get_word_count(wordlist, final)
File "C:\Users\Animesh\Desktop\_zipf.py", line 32, in get_word_count
frequency.append(sum(count[k]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

What should I change in my code ?
Please help

Comment: Is the error coming from the above code or inside `makeregex`?  The code can also fail at `print final[i] + " read!"` if `final[i]` is not a string but it doesn't look like it has reached that far yet.

Comment: Can you output the value of `count[k]` before `sum` is called? Your `count[k]` has something like this `[[], 2]`, try to sum that and it will give you that error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
count[j].append(re.findall(regex[j], data))
```

You're adding list of found words by the regex to the array `count[j]`, so each `count` element is a list of list of strings, thus the error when calling `sum(count[k])`.

I think you want to append to `count[k]` the number of found words:

```
count[j].append(len(re.findall(regex[j], data)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it simpler, you could get rid of the `count = [[] for x in xrange(len(wordlist))]` and just have `count = []` and later in the for loop you make it increment a temporary variable and append that to count after the for loop.

```
size = 0
for j in range (len(wordlist)):
    size += len(re.findall(regex[j], data)) #thanks to CharlesB for this bit
count.append(size) #you could also cut out the middle man and just append frequency
```